# Error in the view when I try eager loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to show data from two tables. I tried this https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application and use eager loading.

I had three tables 'uzytkownik', 'rolaPowiazanie' and 'rola'. 'rolaPowiaznie' connect "uzytkownik' and 'rola' - there's two column 'idRola' and 'idUzytkownik' end this table is invisible in my data model.

My models:

uzytkownik

```
 public partial class uzytkownik
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public uzytkownik()
    {
        this.ocenaPowiazanie = new HashSet<ocenaPowiazanie>();
        this.przedmiotPowWykladowca = new HashSet<przedmiotPowWykladowca>();
        this.grupa = new HashSet<grupa>();
        this.rola = new HashSet<rola>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int idUzytkownik { get; set; }
    public string imie { get; set; }
    public string nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string pesel { get; set; }
    public string haslo { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> stan { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<rola> rola { get; set; }
}
```

rola

```
    public partial class rola
    {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public rola()
    {
        this.uzytkownik = new HashSet<uzytkownik>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int idRola { get; set; }
    public string nazwaRoli { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<uzytkownik> uzytkownik { get; set; }
}
```

They were automaticaly generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model - Database first

As in tutorial I tried eager loading and my controller looks like:

```
public class UzytkownicyController : Controller
{
    private PegazEntities db = new PegazEntities();

    // GET: Uzytkownicy
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var uzytkownicy = db.uzytkownik.Include(x => x.rola);
        return View(uzytkownicy.ToList());
    }
```

In my view I tried:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rola.nazwaRoli)
```

> 'ICollection ' does not contain definition for 'nazwRoli' and no extension method 'nazwaRoli' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be find (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Did I miss something? I tried to do everything as in this tutorial, but something went wrong.

Comment: It doesn't know the type so it's falling back to ICollection. Try using a cast. something like @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((uzytkownik)item.rola).nazwaRoli)

Comment: Not entirely relevant to the question you're asking, but you might want to read the Microsoft guidelines for capitalization (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx); basically, properties and classes/structs/enums should be Pascal case. You're not required to follow those guidelines, but you probably should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `rola` is a collection I wouldn't think you would be able to directly use `DisplayFor` on it. Have you tried iterating over the collection instead?

For example, in your view can you do something like this?

```
@model List<uzytkownik>

@foreach (var uzytkownik in Model)
{
    foreach (var rola in uzytkownik.rola)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rola.nazwaRoli)
    }
}
```

Or if using a `foreach` iterator isn't working then you could just use a classic `for` loop:

```
@model List<uzytkownik>

@for (var i; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j; j < Model[i].rola.Count(); j++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].rola[j].nazwaRoli)
    }
}
```